# Energy required for bringing a quantum particle from infinity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics

In classical electrodynamics, it is very easy to calculate the energy required to bring an electron (or a point charge) from infinity with respect to some point in space. My question is, how do we calculate the energy required to bring a quantum particle from infinity to a point and calculate the final potential energy of the system with respect to some point we choose?

To clarify, in the classical case, we have a defined term of "distance" to put in the electrical potential formula since the particle's position is known. However, in the quantum case, we are working with wavefunctions and probabilities; hence, we do not have a definite position for the particle.